# Need to return an array element from a hashtable based upon if the key's array contains a certain value

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I have a hashtable with two keys, each key is an array.  If one key's array contains a given value, I want to return the same index item from the second key.  Here's the code snippet:

```
$ht=@{"Name" = @("Release", "Build", "Test", "CI/CD")
    "Type" = @("Release Workflow", "Build Workflow", "Testing Workflow", "CI/CD Workflow")
}



if($ht.Name.Contains("Release")){
    
}
```

So for the second statement, I want to return the value "Release Workflow".  So far I'm not having much luck and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
$ht = @{
    "Name" = @("Release", "Build", "Test", "CI/CD")
    "Type" = @(
        "Release Workflow", "Build Workflow"
        "Testing Workflow", "CI/CD Workflow"
    )
}
$key = "Release"

# Might want to use `-contains $key` or `$key -in` here
if($ht.Name.Contains($key)){
    $ht['Type'][$ht['Name'].IndexOf($key)]
}
```

Note that, the `.Contains(..)` array method is case-sensitive, you might want to use `-contains` or `-in` operators for a case-insensitive lookup.

Comment: That got it!  Man, I was sooo close, thank you so much for clarifying this, you saved the day!  Also thanks about case sensitivity, I'll stick in some ToLower() or something like that.  We have files to parse and the rocket surgeons were not consistent with the "name:" value in YAML files, so we have to find it and then try to figure out what the name is which will tell us what it's doing (Github actions).  Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RichardWolford my pleasure, happy to help. I definitely recommend you to use the operators (`-in` or `-contains`) instead of `.Contains($something.ToLower())`, the operators are much more efficient in such case.